# Why do i need overide keyword when implementing an interface

Tags: solidity

Look at this interface:

```
 interface Contract1Interface
 {
     function myfunction(uint) external returns (uint);
 }
```

I have implemented a smartcontract from this interface:

```
contract Contract1 is Contract1Interface 
{
  
  function myfunction(uint param1) override public returns (uint) 
  {
      ...
  }
}
```

I need to put override in the Contract1's function declaration. The compiler gives me an error if i don't.

My question is why ? This function should implicitly be override. In other programming language there is no need to override because we are implementing an interface...

Have I made a mistake ?

Comment: Yes, you have. This is not "other programming languages". That's the rule dictated by this language (i.e., by the compiler), so that's the rule that you should follow. On top of that, I believe that you also need to add `virtual` on the function declaration in the interface.

Comment: virtual was not necessary